# Implement SSL with SSPI: How to start?

Tags: c++, security, winapi, ssl, sspi

I want to implement an SSL client using SSPI.
Where can I find step-by-step guides, code examples, etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google suggested this site: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslclasses.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know this one. 
Do you have any additional references?

Comment: No. Maybe you could describe more precisely what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Some code and white paper using Microsoft Windows SChannel SSPI at www.coastrd.com

Answer (score 1):

Below is google chrome browser implementation . Its a has BSD license, So you can reuse it.

http://chrome-browser.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9084/trunk/src/net/base/ssl_client_socket_win.cc